# I can't see tables, views or indexes in DBA panel in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm new to oracle and have created a connection but now the problem is I can't see any any tables, views or indexes etc which are automatically generated with new connection. I've searched the internet but haven't found what the problem is.

HERE is my current DBA Side window.

[image]

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Does the user you're connecting to have DBA privilege?

Comment: "... which are automatically generated with new connection" - well, nothing is "automatically generated" just because you connect to the database. Screenshot suggests you're on 12c (are you?). Could you describe steps you performed to get to that point?

Comment: Looks like you're connected to the Container database. The schemas, tables, nd indexes you're looking for will be in a pluggable database...which you'll see on the Connections panel, not the DBA panel.

Comment: Figured out. I'm using DBA panel but I should had opened connections window

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to open SQL Developer: View -> Connections -> New Connection and you will get object explorer.

[image]